# Graphically display model coded in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

Assuming that I'm coding out a Resnet 152 model in keras from scratch, does there exist any tool/api which can take my code as input and give out a graphical signal flow diagram so that I can make sure that the model I coded turned out as intended?

I know there exists Keras Model Summary, but how do I interpret skip layer connections from that?

Comment: Have you tried [tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 
`plot_model(your_model, to_file='model.png')`

You will get a .png of your model that shows you how your layers are connected.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.